# Why is the regex not correct on form inputs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my contactform, I added event listeners that are looking for url strings in the input fields. I'm using the regex `(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+` to do the job. All strings in the regex are working fine, except `\\\\` will give a hit on 1 backslash.

Why is the regex ok on https://regexr.com and why is it not working in Javascript?

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j3hsvapm/1/

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED** because Opera does not support the `String.raw` I used 8 backslashes as recommended by @user120242, and now it is working fine.

```js
var formElms = document.querySelectorAll('.testme');
Object.keys(formElms).forEach(function(key) {
    formElms[key].addEventListener('input', function () {
        var result = 'OK';
        var reg = new RegExp("(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\\\\\)+", "gi");
        value = formElms[key].value;
        // console.log(key, ': ', value);
        if (reg.test(value)) result = 'Not allowed';
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result;
    });
});
```

```css
div, input, textarea {
    width: 200px;
    font: 400 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">OK</div>

<br><input class="testme" type="text">
<br><br><textarea class="testme" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Comment: escaping,  \\\\ turns into the string \\, and then regex escapes again, so it becomes \  fyi, you may want to use regex literal syntax since you don't need to compile a custom regex: `reg = /(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+/gi`

Comment: Thanx, I understand the reason now. I have to use `new RegExp` because I have to add variables to it. The snippet above is the smallest snippet to work with. Please do you have a solution with `new RegExp`. and a reg that will hit on 2 backslashes instead of 1 ?

Comment: See the String.raw template tag in the below.  You could also potentially implement your own template tag function for your own customized usage, although most likely String.raw and ${} interpolation will be enough.

Comment: Opera isn't supporting `String.raw` .  @user120242 did give the cross browser answer by using 8 backslashes and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to string escaping:
`"\\\\"` turns into the string `\\`
and then regex escapes again so it becomes `\`

A few solutions:

- `new RegExp("(http:|https:|www|\\/\\/|\\\\\\\\)+","gi")` (8 backslashes)
- `/(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+/gi` (regex literal)
- (template literal and String.raw)
  `` new RegExp(String.raw`(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+`,'gi') ``

The last one is probably the most elegant solution, and will fit your need to use variable substitution.  eg:

```
myvar = "somestring"
console.log(new RegExp(String.raw`^http://${myvar}$`,'gi').test('HTTP://SOMEstring'))
```

Note: OP has pointed out that Opera lacks String.raw support
For those who want to be able to use String.raw, and are using [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/), there is a plugin for String.raw support:
[babel-plugin-transform-string-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-string-raw)
[Sample transpilation online demo](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=opera%2020&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MoFwTglgdg5gdGAhgdwAYBIDeAPAvqoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Ces2015-loose%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.4&externalPlugins=babel-plugin-transform-string-raw%400.0.2)

Using regex literal syntax instead:

```js
var formElms = document.querySelectorAll('.testme');
Object.keys(formElms).forEach(function(key) {
    // console.log(key, formElms[key], formElms[key].value);
    formElms[key].addEventListener('input', function () {
        var result = 'OK';
        var reg = /(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+/gi;
        value = formElms[key].value;
        console.log(key, ': ', value);
        if (reg.test(value)) result = 'Not allowed';
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result;
    });
});
```

```css
div, input, textarea {
    width: 200px;
    font: 400 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">OK</div>

<br><input class="testme" type="text">
<br><br><textarea class="testme" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Demo that shows what is happening with the string escaping.  Note: In regex `\\` matches on the escaped `\` character
And showing how you can use [String.raw template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to avoid string escaping:

```js
str = "(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+"

console.log("str: ",str) // notice that you get \\

re = new RegExp(str,"gi")

console.log(re)
console.log(re.source)

// using template string syntax and the "raw" template tag
str = String.raw`(http:|https:|www|\/\/|\\\\)+`

console.log("raw str: ",str)

re = new RegExp(str,"gi")

console.log(re)
console.log(re.source)
```

Comment: Thanx, I have to use `new RegExp` because I have to add variables to the reg string. My snippet is the smallest snippet to work with. Please do you have a solution with `new RegExp`.that will hit on 2 backslashes instead of 1 ?

Comment: right, so the bottom solution.  or if you don't like String.raw you will have to use `\\\\\\\\` (eight backslashes).  Maybe if you provide a more concrete example (of variable substitution you need) so I can provide a more concrete answer (showing the substitution) for you?

Comment: Opera isn't supporting `String.raw` so I have to use manu manu  backslashes :-) Thank you for giving this solution, I will update my question.